# How to find a element and edit its attributes in a XML file using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file:

```
<srtch Name="tchfn" version="v.1.1.02"  />
<vrttch Name="tchfn 02" version="v.1.1.03"  />
<ghsch Name="tchfn 03" version="v.1.1.04"  />
```

I need to check if `vrttch` exists and if yes I need to change version. If it does not exist need to create new entry.

I am completely new to C#. I have tried `xmlreader`. I able to check if its of type element but I could not set the attributes.

Any help would be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

        XmlNodeList xNodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//vrttch");

        if (xNodeList.Count != 0)
        {
            xNodeList[0].Attributes["version"].Value = "Whateva";
        }
        xDoc.Save("XMLFile1.xml");
    }
```

One issue you might have with this is the path of the xml file.  To find where your project's local path is right click on your project and click `open in File explorer`, and then go to `bin`, `debug`, and that's where you xml file should be

if that sounds too hard for you, it's probably easier to make the path an absolute path for instance:

```
xDoc.Load(@"c:\temp\XMLFile1.xml");
```

be sure to put a root node in your XML, like so

```
<root>
  <srtch Name="tchfn" version="v.1.1.02"  />
  <vrttch Name="tchfn 02" version="v.1.1.03"  />
  <ghsch Name="tchfn 03" version="v.1.1.04"  />
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and call Descendents("vrttch") to see if its null. If so it's not there